# Grover stop iterations if a condition is met

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm

My Qiskit circuit generates many states and I call "solutions" the ones whose last qubit is |1>.
Their number is unknown in advance.

By using Grover, the main instructions are

```
problem = AmplificationProblem(oracle,state_preparation=circ, is_good_state=good_state)
grover = Grover(sampler=Sampler())
result = grover.amplify(problem)
```

It works well for small problems but the optimal number of iterations automatically estimated by Qiskit (say I_optim) increases very quickly with the size of the circuit and I don't want all solutions (that are given in "results"), just one.

Is it possible to iterate as long as condition is not met?
Something like this:

```
stop = the most probable state is a solution OR current number of iterations >= I_optim
grover = Grover(iterations=<as long as NOT stop>, sampler=Sampler())
```